# What is the meaning of urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:function:string-contains?

Tags: authorization, xacml, xacml3, abac, alfa

I would like to know the explanation of below function
urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:function:string-contains

I have a requirement that the user ID string needs to compared with strings containing Suresh, suresh pelluru, Suresh prakash, Suresh Group etc...

Which function is use ful to compare with suresh ( Case Sensitive)

Thanks,
Suresh Pelluru.

Answer (score 1):

You have several string comparison functions in XACML:

- urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal
- urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:function:string-equal-ignore-case
- urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-greater-than-or-equal
- urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-less-than
- urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-less-than-or-equal
- urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-is-in
- urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:function:string-starts-with
- urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:function:string-ends-with
- **urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:function:string-contains**
- urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-regexp-match
- urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-at-least-one-member-of

`string-contains` takes two arguments of data-type [string](http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string) and returns a [boolean](http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#boolean).  The function returns `true` if the second string contains the first string, and `false` otherwise. Equality testing is done as defined for `urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal`.

Example:

- `string-contains("alice", "alice is in the woods")`: this returns true.
- `string-contains("alice is in the woods", "alice")`: this returns false.

The entire list of functions is [available here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-3.0-core-spec-os-en.html#_Toc325047234).

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement if you need to compare the user name from a list of usernames in a case sensitive manner then you may use one of the way as below in your condition/target etc.:

```
<Apply FunctionId=”urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:function:any-of”>
 <Function FunctionId=”urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal”/>
  <AttributeValue DataType=”http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string”>suresh</AttributeValue>
   <Apply FunctionId=”urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-bag”>
      <AttributeValue DataType=”http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string”>Suresh</AttributeValue>
      <AttributeValue DataType=”http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string”>suresh</AttributeValue>
      <AttributeValue DataType=”http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string”>suresh pelluru</AttributeValue>
      <AttributeValue DataType=”http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string”>Suresh Prakash</AttributeValue>
   </Apply>
</Apply>
```